# emojiarea no se muestra

Tags: javascript, html

hola tengo un bug el plugin emojiarea no se muestra
alguien sabe como arreglar este error?

probe moviendo el id a un div pero tampoco se muestra
en mi web subida a un host funciona correctamente pero en local no funciona

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
          pickerPosition: "bottom",
          filtersPosition: "bottom",
          tonesStyle: "bullet"
      });
  })(jQuery);
  </script>
<textarea id="#emojionearea1" name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te muestra algún error en consola o algo? Compruebas que el css se ejecuta?

Comment: @matahombres nop ningun error en la consola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Max tu problema es que tienes tu textarea asi:

`<textarea id="#emojionearea1" name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>`

Si te das cuenta en el id tienes **#** te esta sobrando para que te funcione sin problemas deberia ser asi:

`<textarea id="emojionearea1" name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>`

Del resto no veo problemas.

te adjunto un link con el ejemplo [code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxc34v2/)  (solo con el cambio que te mencione)

Comment: hum tampoco es ya le quite la almuadilla y sigue sin mostrarme el icono para los emojis el codigo lo saque de aqui https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea pero no entiendo por que en local no me lo muestra pero si en mi web

Comment: @Max actualice la respuesta y te agregue un ejemplo con lo que hice y si me funciona sin problemas.